# Running Git command from Expect script fails

Tags: git, tcl, expect

I am writing an Expect script to pull the latest code from our dev server each time a new server instance is spawned on AWS. The idea is that when the new server is created, the script is run at boot before being placed behind the load balancer. It works perfectly unless Git aborts because of a conflict. Here is the code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout 240

spawn /xyz/pullfromdev
expect "*?assphrase*"
send -- "<mypass>\r"

expect {
        "Aborting" {
                set response $expect_out(buffer)
                set format [split $response "\n"]
                cd /var/www/html
                foreach line $format {
                        if { !([string range $line 0 8] == "Identity " || [string range $line 0 8] == "Updating " || [string range $line 0 5] == "error:" || [string range $line 0 6] == "Please," || [string range $line 0 7] == "Aborting" || [string length $line] == 1 ) } {
                                open "| git checkout -- [string trim $line]"
                        }
                }
                spawn /xyz/pullfromdev
                expect "*?assphrase*"
                send -- "<mypass>\r"
        }
}

expect eof
```

Basically I am splitting the output buffer and trying to run `git checkout -- <filename>` for each file that has a conflict. Then trying to pull again to hopefully complete successfully.

The issue is with the line:

```
open "| git checkout -- [string trim $line]"
```

It simply does not perform any action apparently and i do not get any error.  The script tries to pull again from the dev server and aborts because the git checkout did not occur and the conflicts remain. TCL is a bit foreign to me so perhaps its a syntax issue? I have tried spawn as well as exec but they do not seem to work either. Conflicts remain and git aborts.

However, if I run `git checkout -- <filename>` via the command line, then that particular file is no longer conflicting (because the checkout actually occurred). So the issue really is getting the git checkout command to run from the Expect script which i am failing to do somehow.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

If it helps at all, this is on CentOS 5 and the 'pullfromdev' script referenced in the code is simply:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/www/html
ssh-agent bash -c 'ssh-add /xyz/<identity>; git pull'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When opening a pipeline, everything apart from the first character is a Tcl list of arguments (the first `|` is special). This means you should use this:

```
open |[list git checkout -- [string trim $line]]
```

Comment: If that doesn't fix it, consider using strace to see where things are hanging…

Answer (score 1):

You can't use == to compare strings in TCL. Try the [string compare](http://wiki.tcl.tk/10163) or [regexp](http://wiki.tcl.tk/986) commands.

Comment: You cannot use `==`, but `=` and `eq` or the string compare command all work.

Comment: @resmon6 @schlenk thanks for your replies.  Funny enough, `==` works and printing afterwards confirms this!

However even if I remove the foreach loop and replace with `open "| git checkout -- <filename>"`, the command still does not work.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The only thing I can think to do is to change `open "| git checkout -- [string trim $line]"` to `send_user -- [string trim $line]` to make sure you're getting standard filenames with no special characters or <> symbols in them. I can't think of any other reason it wouldn't work.

Comment: @resmon6 yep just tried `send_user` and the filenames are correct.  Same result as `puts`.  Just cant figure out why the git command wont run.  If I try `puts [exec pwd]` just before the command, it shows im in the correct directory, and im pointing to the correct files in the git command as the `send_user` test shows. It's driving me nuts!

Comment: Try this:

`set fid [open "| git checkout -- [string trim $line]"]`
`send_user -- [read $fid]`

Comment: Both `==` and (from 8.4 onwards) `eq` can test for string equality, but `==` will attempt to do a numeric equality test first.